# Dual Solution of Truncated Primal LP

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Given the LP
$\min\{c^Tx:Ax\geqslant b, x\geqslant 0\},$
suppose $x^*$ is an optimal solution (with finite objective), and let $y^*$ be an optimal solution to the dual. Now suppose we truncate the above LP by removing all variables for which $x_j^* = 0$. Let's call the new inputs $\bar{A}$ and $\bar{c}$, and we solve
$\min\{\bar{c}^Tx:\bar{A}x\geqslant b, x\geqslant 0\}.$
Let us call the new solutions $\bar{x}^*$ and $\bar{y}^*$. $\bar{x}^*$ will be $x^*$ without the zero variables since that's a feasible solution with the same objective, and removing variables cannot decrease the optimal value.

The question I am trying to answer is: Is $\bar{y}^*$ optimal to the original (non-truncated) LP? Here's what I have so far:

- $c^Tx^* = \bar{c}^T\bar{x}^* = b^T\bar{y}^*$ so the objective values are equal.
- $0 = (\bar{c}-\bar{A}^T\bar{y}^*)^T\bar{x}^* = (c-A^T\bar{y}^*)^Tx^*$ and $0 = (\bar{A}\bar{x}^*-b)^T\bar{y}^* = (Ax^*-b)^T\bar{y}^*$, both due to the 0 components of $x^*$, so complementary slackness holds.
- Now we know that $\bar{A}^T\bar{y}^* \leqslant \bar{c}$. I'm stuck trying to show that $A^T\bar{y}^* \leqslant c$. I really hope I'm not missing something obvious... **[EDIT]**: I guess I should mention that it occurred to me that if there existed a $j$ such that $(A^T\bar{y}^*)_j > c_j$ then this would constitute a "negative reduced-cost column", but does that necessarily contradict the optimality of $x^*$ to the original LP? My knowledge of LPs is somewhat piecemeal and I don't know enough about issues of degeneracy, non-uniqueness, etc.